# How to take screenshot of a layout having a camera preview and text view?

Tags: android, screenshot, surfaceview

[i want to take screenshot of camera and map and address text view only, whenever i try to take screenshot its only saving map and text area but the camera area gets all white screen only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm8Sj.jpg)Here is my xml layout , and i want to take screenshot of relative layout with id rl_photo, but after taking screenshot of layout its only taking the map and textview but not camera image , camera image gets all white screen .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save Photo"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/tv_save"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/rl_action"
    android:id="@+id/rl_photo"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/map"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#66000000"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/tv_latlong"
    android:text="xbdjhgjrejgtrjbtbjr"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rl_action"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_capture"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/record"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/flip"
        android:id="@+id/img_flip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/gallery"
        android:id="@+id/img_gallery"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

For screenshot

1. Add image view on above of FrameLayout
2. While capturing the ss set camera bitmap in image view and make Imageview **visible** one process is done to make image view **invisible**
3. For SS follow below Process

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Save Photo"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rl_action">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageViewOFCamera"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_latlong"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/map"
            android:background="#66000000"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="xbdjhgjrejgtrjbtbjr"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_action"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button_capture"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/record" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_flip"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/flip" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_gallery"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/gallery" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

for ss capture in java File

```
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    bitmap = ScreenshotUtil.getInstance().takeScreenshotForView( rl_photo); 


public class ScreenshotUtil {
    private static ScreenshotUtil mInstance;

    private ScreenshotUtil() {
    }

    public static ScreenshotUtil getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            synchronized (ScreenshotUtil.class) {
                if (mInstance == null) {
                    mInstance = new ScreenshotUtil();
                }
            }
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
    
    public Bitmap takeScreenshotForView(View view) {
        view.measure( MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec( view.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec( view.getHeight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ) );
        view.layout( (int) view.getX(), (int) view.getY(),
                (int) view.getX() + view.getMeasuredWidth(),
                (int) view.getY() + view.getMeasuredHeight() );

        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled( true );
        view.buildDrawingCache( true );
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( view.getDrawingCache() );
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled( false );

        return bitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap takeScreenshotForScreen(Activity activity) {
        return takeScreenshotForView( activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView() );
    }
}
```